# paginaton dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I want to have a dropdown that will have the user select which record number they want to be on? so if I ave 200 records in db, it will have 4 pages and dropdown will look like this

"Just an idea..not an exact code"

```
<select>
<option>1-50</option>
<option>51-100</option>
<option>101-150</option>
<option>151-200</option>
</select>
```

I seen pagination with other types in jquery but not dropdown. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-a-jquery-pagination-system/) excellent tutorial/plugin for doing pagination with jQuery. You can bind the change event of your dropdown and then use next, previous callbacks on it.