# Pagination inside a drop down in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<select multiple>
<option></option>
  <option>a1</option>
  <option>b1</option>
  <option>c1</option>
  <option>d1</option>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  <option>u100</option>
  <option>v100</option>
  <option>w100</option>
  <option>x100</option>
  <option>y100</option>
  <option>z100</option>
</select>
```

here i have 2600 options how can i show
I have drop downs with Thousands of options so i had decided to put pagination inside that drop down.but i'm not getting any idea on this.
I'm using chosen plugin for drop down

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311652/paginaton-dropdown-with-jquery) question should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Don't do pagination, try to implement like https://www.devbridge.com/sourcery/components/jquery-autocomplete/

Comment: pagination in dropdown? really how to do that @devendra tata

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311652/paginaton-dropdown-with-jquery) example wont work ...i need like drop down but its showing like pages @ Alex Gaudiosi

Answer (score 2):

First of all in a dropdown **you don't need** paging. Paging is a good option for mixed tables.

For optional dropdowns you can use **autocompleter**s. Autocompleters are very user friendly solution.

But if realy want to paging on option you can create a listener which is listening next or previous button or option then get new options from data list.

Here is a simple example for you: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfaL12yb/)

You can append more elements if you want. But it is not a good solution.

But **again and again** if you realy want paging in dropdowns use `<ul> <li>` combination and create more user friendly option area.

Example (You have to define a lot of things for don't get error):

```
<select id="select">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option value="front">Next Page</option>
  <option value="back">Pre Page</option>
</select>


$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = [4,5,6,7,8,9];
    var changeIndex = 0;
    $('#select').change(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
        if($(this).val()=='front'){
        $(this).empty();
        var newOption = '<option>'+data[changeIndex++]+'</option>';
        $(this).append(newOption);
        $(this).append(' <option value="front">Next Page</option>');
        $(this).append(' <option value="back">Pre Page</option>');
      }
      if($(this).val()=='back'){
        $(this).empty();
        var newOption = '<option>'+data[changeIndex-2]+'</option>';
        changeIndex--;
        $(this).append(newOption);
        $(this).append(' <option value="front">Next Page</option>');
        $(this).append(' <option value="back">Pre Page</option>');
      }
    });
});
```